# Use vendor DNS?

Tags: dns

I use AkrutoSync to sync Outlook on my laptop to my smartphone.  I can avoid the cloud and sync over home WiFi.  AkrutoSync presents an Exchange interface to the phone.  In the past, it only worked if my laptop had a fixed IP address.  Fixing the address can cause problems if it connects to the Access Point after another laptop, if the other laptop has the IP address that my laptop wants.

AkrutoSync has solved this recently by allowing users to choose a "*Simple* method which uses a DNS hostname (akrname.com) that resolves the IP address of your computer automatically. This prevents the IP change message from appearing. This will also allow you to sync your computer and phone on a different network. As long as the computer and phone are connected to the same network/router, the sync will work."

Not really being an IT/IM professional, I can't say that I understand it.  I assume that the explanation was more basic because it's not really AkrutoSync's job to educate me on all things IT/IM.  It seems to be a small business, and taking on public education of IT/IM is probably not feasible (and to be frank, it's not necessarily done by big corporations either).

Is the quoted explanation enough to determine whether it is safe safe to use this 3rd party DNS?  If I wanted to establish enough background to make sense of the quoted response and exercise judgement on using the *Simple* method, without turning it into a professional undertaking, are there particular web pages that are well targeted to such a desired level of detail?

Thanks.

Comment: Your laptop should be configured with the fixed IP Address. The device that is handing out addresses should be configured not to hand out that particular address. This is typically referred to as a "reservation". Once configured, the device will then hand out addresses except for that particular address. Can you make these modifications?

Comment: Using older versions of AkrutoSync, my laptop was configured with a static IP address *before* `akrname.com` was made available. I'm unsure of what you mean by "the device will hand out...". Are you talking about my local modem/router? Currently, its IP address is the same as `Default Gateway`, `DHCP Server`, and `DNS Servers`.

Comment: Re. "Can you make these modifications?", my modem/router doesn't avoid handing out the static IP address if my laptop is off. But my question is whether there is risk in using a vendor DNS who is not a big name established organization. I guess that's where my ignorance of the internet lies, it's always been a bit foggy how one ensures that domain names are resolved in a trustworthy fashion.

Comment: i am referring to this line "Fixing the address can cause problems if it connects to the Access Point after another laptop, if the other laptop has the IP address that my laptop wants.". I am saying that you should go back to that old method, and give your laptop a fixed address. Then, go to your "modem/router" and set it so that it never allocates (hands out) that particular address to any other device. That address is to be reserved for your laptop only. There is a section in your router called "DHCP", and that is what you need to modify, in order to make this happen.

Comment: Ah!  That was very educational. There is indeed a panel `Address Reservation` under `DHCP Server`. I was able to associate my laptop's WiFi MAC address with the static IPv4 address. This is in fact a very good answer for my underlying problem, but I regret that I can't mark it as the answer for this question. This question is more about whether it is safe to use a DNS that is not some large well-recognized establishment. I think I'm going to have to figure that out over time with more online reading. But thanks, I very much appreciate the very helpful information.